# Getting error while upload file

Tags: lightning, files, contentversion

I am trying to upload file in the files section in lightning. i am getting below error -

[image]

**I am getting this error only when attaching an email message which has a pdf attached to it.**
I tried deactivating the trigger on Content version but still face the same issue.
It does not work for any object.

Answer (score 0):

The File Upload window does not do a good job of displaying error messages, so this could be the result of many things.

1. Validation Rule on ContentVersion
2. Insufficient Access Rights to
   upload a File
3. An error during trigger processing on
   ContentVersion, ContentDocument, or ContentDocumentLink

You say this ONLY happens with .msg files that have a .pdf included in it, which implies that you are able to upload other files, which rules out (2). The fact that the inclusion of the PDF is needed to reproduce this error would seem to rule out (1) as validation rules wouldn't be able to reach into the content/data of file. This leaves apex running from a trigger as the most likely culprit. You mentioned you disabled a trigger on ContentVersion, but the upload of a File will also initiate triggers on the ContentDocument and ContentDocumentLink objects. I'd look there.

Comment: There is no trigger on those. Just the one on content version which I deactivated. And yes I am able to upload other files, even .msg with .doc works fine. Just issue with pdf.

Answer (score 0):

This error could be caused because the file is too big. Try uploading a msg with a smaller pdf file attached or freeing up space in your org by deleting files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).